# What are the most well-understood vocal animal languages?

Tags: ethology, communication, language

Just as the [Bee dance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waggle_dance), for a "language", I mean that there are vocal pattens, or "grammar".

In the nature, there are many intelligent animals like human beings.

Bird songs, whale songs, dogs?

In fact, bird vocalization includes both bird calls and bird songs. There are Parrots, hummingbirds and songbirds,...

I wish to know the most well-understood vocal animal languages. Which species?

Comment: "most well-understood" is rather subjective, this question doesn't really fit the Q&A format well. It is also [cross-posted on CogSci](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/what-are-the-most-well-understood-vocal-animal-languages), so I'm closing it here on this site.

Comment: @MadScientist Why subjective? *Apis mellifera* is one of the most well studied animals, if not THE most. Is this subjective? I know of some African monkeys that we know have distinct words for "snake", "eagle", "hierarchy above", "hierarchy below". I know some whales can repeat exactly the same song one and a half hour long. I think the question is very interesting, and it will have different answers here than it will on CogSci, and probably very interesting answers. So I vote to reopen it.